# Angular Directive Advice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I have a data driven directive that takes a list of items and creates a list of radio buttons, although they've been skinned to look like buttons.

Everything is working fine, however, I would like to define an image URL within each item and then within ng-repeat display the image (the image would represent the button). At present the image URL is defined in the CSS which means I can only have one type of button. It needs to be more dynamic that that.

As usual any pointers would be really great.

Cheers.

---

### CSS

```
        #buttonBox label {
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 13px;
            margin-right: 46px;
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        #buttonBox label:before {
            content: "";
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            background-image: url('app/images/blue.png');
        }

        #buttonBox input[type=radio] {
            display: none;
        }

        #buttonBox input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
            content: "";
            background-image: url('app/images/yellow.png');
        }
```

---

### HTML

```
<da-buttons model="phone" items='phones' checked-index="0"></da-buttons>
```

---

### Controller (these are the items)

```
$scope.phones = [ {
    text: "Android",
    group: "phoneGroup",
    value: 9
}, {
    text: "iOS",
    group: "phoneGroup",
    value: 10
}, {
    text: "Blackberry",
    group: "phoneGroup",
    value: 11
}];
```

---

### Directive

```
var directives = angular.module('myApp.directives');

directives.directive('daButtons', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            items: '=',
            checkedIndex: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'template/button-group.html',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.onItemChange = function(item) {
                scope.model = item;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

---

### Template: button-group.html

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items' id="buttonBox">
    <input
       type="radio"
       name="{{item.group}}"
       value="{{item.value}}"
       ng-model="model.value"
       ng-checked="$index==checkedIndex">
    <label ng-click="onItemChange(item)">{{item.text}}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> At present the image URL is defined in the CSS which means I can only have one type of button.

You can use this to your advantage. Since the image comes from css, create different classes for each image. Such as:

```
.image-1 {
    background-image: url('path/to/image_1.png');
}

.image-2 {
    background-image: url('path/to/image_2.png');
}

.image-3 {
    background-image: url('path/to/image_3.png');
}
```

Then you can make use of the `ng-class` directive to decide which image to show. For example (Omitting other details of your template only for easier understanding):

```
<input ng-class="{determineClass(): true}[0]">
```

`determineClass()` is a scope function in your directive that will decide which of the `image-*` classes to apply based on your requirements.

Comment: So far this is the best solution. I'll let you know how it goes. Thank you very much for your input it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use inline approach. it will avoid css modification.
If phones JSON is dynamic, it's even better, you don't need to do any changes to see that directive will pick up images correcly.

```
$scope.phones = [ {
        text: "Android",
        group: "phoneGroup",
        value: 9б
        image: 'img1'
    }, {
        text: "iOS",
        group: "phoneGroup",
        value: 10,
        image: 'img2'
    }, {
        text: "Blackberry",
        group: "phoneGroup",
        value: 11,
        image: 'img3
    }];
```

directive:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items' id="buttonBox">
    <input
       type="radio"
       name="{{item.group}}"
       value="{{item.value}}"
       ng-model="model.value"
       ng-checked="$index==checkedIndex"
       class="set whatever class you need"
       style="background-image:url({{item.image}})>
    <label ng-click="onItemChange(item)">{{item.text}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this approach although I'm not sure if it's a good idea to mix markup and CSS. I prefer a clear separation of concerns. Thank you very much for your input it's much appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate patterns as well. but the case is that directive it's already SoC, as it's designed to work with html/css. having hardcode in css is not a pattern too. so feel free to choose what's appropriate for you :)

Comment: Like I said I'm not sure. You raise an interesting point about directives being designed to work with both HTML & CSS so maybe it is acceptable. Thanks for your thought provoking comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible and unobtrusive approach would be to use CSS classes to define custom appearance. In controller you then define `className` property:

```
$scope.phones = [{
    text: "Android",
    group: "phoneGroup",
    value: 9
}, {
    text: "iOS",
    group: "phoneGroup",
    value: 10,
    className: 'fade-button' // <--- whatever
}, {
    text: "Blackberry",
    group: "phoneGroup",
    value: 11,
    className: 'circle-button' // <---
}];
```

and in template:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items' id="buttonBox" class="{{item.className}}">
    ...
</div>
```

Now you only need to define CSS rules to style your new checkbox:

```
#buttonBox.fade-button label:before {
    background-image: url(some-image.png);
    background-color: red;
}
#buttonBox.fade-button input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    background-image: url(...);
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/YnIbCbW9jnzsZSMX8abL?p=preview

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to couple data with class names. My data isn't dynamic but I still wouldn't like to go down this road. Thank you very much for your input it's much appreciated.

Comment: Well, I don't know then how else you can "define an image URL within each item".

Comment: There is nothing wrong with an image URL in your data, that is completely different to having a class name in your data.

Comment: `There is nothing wrong with an image URL in your data`? Why? The same mixute data with representation. This is the same as having class name. Except that with className you have much more flexibility. Say tomorrow you have new requirement to make one specific button styled totally differently and you can't solve it with an image. However with a class name it's not a problem.

Comment: I'm talking about data coming from a server not sitting locally.If you was working with a backend developer who's providing this data he would't want to put your class names in his data.Suppose there were other clients consuming this service why would they need your class names? An image URL in the data is fine because it's not coupling your data to some specific style.In this instance if there was a new requirement to replace the image then it would be driven from the backend where you wouldn't have to do a thing.It's good practice to think like this even if the data is local such as my case.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But you probably misunderstand my point. I don't mean to you should have a className in database for each row. In fact I'm not even talking about CSS classes. I am saying that in order to achieve the best flexibility each item should carry some unique identifier (I just called it className). You can use groupName or even id to wire up *unique* className in HTML. So that you can simple style separate elements independently.

Comment: You said "In fact I'm not even talking about CSS classes." Really? You advised class="{{item.className}}" that looks like classes to me.